# node.js async mapSeries of smembers

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis

Having a list of `keys` I try to fetch all there `values` from redis, like following

```
 async.mapSeries(['offer','find'],function (seed) {
    client.smembers(string);
},
   function(err, resultArr) {
      err && console.trace(err);
      console.log(resultArr)
})
```

Of course it doesn't work, what I expect to see that `resultArr` contains the values of keys ['offer','find'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to add any callbacks to delegate the data forward. Change the iterator function to something like this:

```
function (seed, cb) {
  client.smembers(string, cb);
}
```

This instructs Redis to tell async that it is done transforming the data, and what the result is. You current code never reaches the final callback since async never considers the loop to be done.